# QRemoteObjectNode::remoteObjectAdded signal does not fire

Tags: qt, remoteobject

While learning how to use QtRO tech preview module, I tried a simple 3 node network ( A registry node, a source object remoting node, and a client node).

registry node main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRemoteObjectRegistryHost>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QRemoteObjectRegistryHost host(QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557"));

    return a.exec();
}
```

source node main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRemoteObjectHost>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTimer timer;
    timer.start(10000);

    QRemoteObjectHost host;
    if(!host.setHostUrl(QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556"))) qDebug() << "Host url " << host.lastError();
    if(!host.setRegistryUrl(QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557"))) qDebug() << "Reg url " << host.lastError();

    if(!host.enableRemoting(&timer, "HostTimer")) qDebug() << "Remoting error " << host.lastError();

    return a.exec();
}
```

client node main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRemoteObjectNode>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QRemoteObjectNode node(QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557"));

    QObject::connect(&node, &QRemoteObjectNode::remoteObjectAdded,
                     [](const QRemoteObjectSourceLocation& info){
        qDebug() << "New source added : " << info;
    });

    qDebug() << "Waiting for registry ";
    node.waitForRegistry(10000);

    qDebug() << "Already here sources : " << node.registry()->sourceLocations();

    QTimer timer;
    timer.start(5000);

    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout,
                     [&](){
        qDebug() << "New sources list : " << node.registry()->sourceLocations();
    });


    return a.exec();
}
```

I begin by starting the registry node, then the client node and finally the source node, with this launch sequence I expect to get the remoteObjectAdded fired up, but It didn't.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question.

I used the wrong signal source in the connect method call.

the client node will be as :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRemoteObjectNode>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QRemoteObjectNode node(QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557"));

    QObject::connect(node.registry(), &QRemoteObjectRegistry::remoteObjectAdded,
                     [](const QRemoteObjectSourceLocation& info){
        qDebug() << "New source added : " << info;
    });

    qDebug() << "Waiting for registry ";
    node.waitForRegistry(10000);

    qDebug() << "Already here sources : " << node.registry()->sourceLocations();

    QTimer timer;
    timer.start(5000);

    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout,
                     [&](){
        qDebug() << "New sources list : " << node.registry()->sourceLocations();
    });


    return a.exec();
}
```

It is the registry who fire the signal not the node, It sound logic after all the source nodes are connected to the registry, so it fire the remoteObjectAdded signal.